# Append string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I've been trying to find and replace width & height of an image using the following url

http://res.cloudinary.com/chathura-rupasinghe/image/upload/v1453573679/manhattan_logo_kd7ts8.png

into

http://res.cloudinary.com/chathura-rupasinghe/image/upload/c_fill,h_80,w_80/v1453573679/manhattan_logo_kd7ts8.png

notice c_fill,h_80,w_80
i need to append c_fill,h_80,w_80 between upload/  {mystringgoeshere}  /
how do i do it ? im very bad at regex.thanks

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Just asking for a REGEX is frowned upon, that said: If you always have `/upload/` where you want to replace, you can do `url = url.replace(/\/upload\//,"/upload/c_fill,h_80,w_80/")`

Comment: hi i have no idea how to do it as i mention i'm very bad at regex.:(

Comment: Start from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)